# MongoDB $and use cases

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

What is the use cases of $and operator.

Looks like those are same

```js
    this.matchModel.find({
      color: 'red',
      size: 'large'
    })

    this.matchModel.find({
      $and: [
        {
          color: 'red'
        },
        {
          size: 'large'
        }
      ]
    })
```

Aren't those same?

Comment: They mean the same. The first syntax shows the implicit usage of `$and` operator. Sometimes you may have a situation to use the `$and` explicitly in a more useful way like in these [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they mean the same, but they do make more sense if you want to combine it with other operators like `$or`. Consider the logic below, it makes code more readable too.

```
this.matchModel.find({
  $or: [
    {
      $and: [
        {
          size: { $gt: 1}
        },
        {
          size: { $lt: 5}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      color: 'red'
    }
  ]
})
```

Here the logic is `(size greater than 1 and less than 5) OR (color is red)`